# Difference between methods Matrix<T> Divide(double scalar) and Matrix<T> DivideByThis(double scalar) in MathNet Numerics?

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm looking at the documentation for DenseMatrix in MathNet Numerics which can be found [here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseMatrix.htm#Divide). I found two method definitions `Matrix<T> Divide(double scalar)` and `Matrix<T> DivideByThis(double scalar)` which both seem to return a Matrix and accept a double scalar.

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `m` is a matrix of type `Matrix<double>` and `s` is a scalar of type `double`, then

- `m.Divide(s)` is equivalent to `m/s` where the scalar is the divisor
- `m.DivideByThis(s)` is equivalent to `s/m` where the scalar is the dividend (point-wise)

Beware that both operations are point-wise divisions, so `DivideByThis` does *not* do a matrix inversion or pseudo-inversion but instead divides the scalar by each value of the matrix.

Unfortunately the tool used to generate the API reference has some issues and fails to render the xml docs in this case. We hope to replace it with something more useful and better integrated into the docs in the future.